# JavaScript and microphone audio stream

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, stream, microphone

Since HTML5 isn't ready yet, and getUserMedia doesn't work in browsers i have tested, I am asking that is there any "wrappers" so I could grap audio stream from microphone and send it to server with Javascript. Similar wrapper has been made with web cameras: (google for a "jquery-webcam-plugin". Two link restriction), but I haven't found any similar things for microphone audio streaming.

Audio can be in any commonly known format.

Flash is not my daily basis, flash tips might not help.

Since Google gears has been deprecated, I think it is not wise to use [AudioApi](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/AudioAPI). [This](http://caniuse.com/#search=Stream%20API) is not a good news either, so I am guessing that only choices are Java and Flash.

I will appreciate every hint and tip I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Flash is not my daily basis".  Your other option is Java, but that's less user-friendly.  If you're going to require a plug-in (and you'll have to until getUserMedia() is implemented), you might as well make it Flash.

Here is a project that wraps a simple Flash app with a Javascript API that streams audio via an HTTP post to a web-server of your choice:

https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

It's not ideal, but it works and does not require a clunky Flash Media Server.

Comment: Great, exactly what i was looking for. How did you find this? 4 days old. Anyways, accepted answer.

Comment: I created it :-).  It still needs some tweaks, but the basic idea is there.  If you've got ideas/code for improvements, feel free to contribute to the project or add "issues" on the project page.

Comment: @IanMcGrawn is there any method to record audio to a string etc in Wami Recorder ? 
 I mean i wanna do small manipulations using webAudio / mozAudio and i dont want the file to go to server and then come back to client ? so is there any suggestion on how to allow it to directly send the buffer / in form of base64 string packets ? or even the whole file as base 64 string as a whole ?